# Properties not being substituted in applicationContext.xml

Tags: spring, properties, applicationcontext

I'm facing a very weird issue. I'm tring to configure the properties of my datasource declared in my spring applicationcontext.xml file via a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer class. The application context file looks like this:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:ws="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core" xmlns:wss="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet"
xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
    http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.4.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<!--  Spring configurations used by LCM Impl classes -->
<bean id="lcmPropertyConfigurer"
       class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:/activemq.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:/jdbc.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy- method="close">
<property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driverClassName}" />
<property name="url" value="${db.url}"/>
<property name="username" value="${db.username}"/>
<property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
</beans>
```

I have tried using the context:property-placeholder tag as well but it doesn't seem to have any effect. The above mentioned properties files are deployed successfully under the WEB-INF/classes directory as well.

For some reason, the spring container is able to load the properties files(checked with an invalide properties file and it throws a FNF exception) but not able to substitute the property placeholders with their values.

I'm using a tomcat 7 WS with the CATALINA.BASE pointing to my runtime. Has anybody faced this issue before? Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Take that leading slash out of the values:

```
        <value>classpath:activemq.properties</value>
        <value>classpath:jdbc.properties</value>
```

Comment: Yup, tried that. Getting a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ${db.driverClassName} when i tried to access the jdbctemplate in my code.

Comment: Yes, but that means reading the properties WORKED.  That exception says you don't have the JDBC driver JAR in your CLASSPATH.

Comment: Hmm, I tried substituting the property placeholder for the driver class name with the name of the driver class directly. It works as expected. So, the driver is getting loaded onto the classpath.

Comment: Is the key name in the driver class correctly entered into your property placeholder?

Comment: Yes, if you mean the key in the properties file. I copy pasted the key from the properties file initially and when that didn't work, copied the value of the key. There are no issues there.

Comment: Is this a web app?  Do you have a context loader listener in your web.xml to load the app context XML from the CLASSPATH?

Comment: Yes,I do. I use the 'org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener' class and specify the path of the appcontext file in the 'contextConfigLocation' param of the listener declaration.

Comment: <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

Answer (score 0):

Try the following configuration.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:activemq.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:jdbc.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The issue is likely the fact that you even named the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer bean. Most Spring internal beans are not given an id, as the framework is configured to look for certain bean names, and often the default bean name is the auto-generated name based on the object type.